# Is it possible to write "proper" Python code in Matillion?

Tags: python-3.x, matillion

For those who don't know, Matillion is an ETL/ELT tool that can be used to handle Snowflake data flows (among other).
One interesting feature is that we can write script tasks in either bash or python.

I had a similar experience in the past with SQL Server Integration Services where it was possible to write C# within tasks as well.

IMHO this presented two big flaws

1. SSIS packages being stored as "blob" made them extremely ill suited to version control. Any tiny change (like just adjusting a task on a pipeline) usually made comparison between two versions practically impossible
2. Sharing code between tasks was extremely difficult (was it possible???)

Matillion "jobs" are stored as json and, like SSIS, it is impossible to compare two versions of the same job, regardless how tiny the change
Also, coding something big in python within a simple text window is just not thinkable

So, I would like to write my Python code outside Matillion and just use Matillion tasks as "glue" between the different functions/packages I would write outside.

Has someone experience of doing this?

How can I make my Python file/package available to Matillion Python scripts?
How could I handle different versions of my Python packages in the different Matillion "Versions" of my jobs?

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to tell that I am a Matillion "beginner" as well as a Python "beginner"...

Comment: What are these Python tasks intended to do that Matillion is not suited for?

Comment: Anything complex where I might encapsulate shared logic in a central repository such as a library/package. We currently do use python in Matillion but keep it to the minimum for the reasons described (lack of compare capability between versions and inability to share between jobs). I know we can create shared jobs but that is different from sharing a set of functions

Comment: If you're a python beginner AND a Matillion beginner, I'd suggest focusing on Matillion first and getting a good understanding of what can and can't be done with the standard components before adding "big" python scripts into the mix. You might also be interested in this blog post from Matillion about integrating python scripts: https://www.matillion.com/resources/blog/offload-large-python-scripts/

Answer (score 2):

I am sure that by now you might have figured something out.
For everyone, in case they are looking, here is another method:

Within Matillion there is a python script component.
We can use that to trigger python scripts outside of Matillion.
I am doing it all the time with the following snippet:

```
import sys
import os

return_var=os.system("sshpass -p <Remote_Machine_User_Password> ssh <Remote_Machine_User>@<Remote_Machine_IP> -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no '/path/to/python/executable/in/remote/machine /path/to/python/script/in/remote/machine'")
print(return_var)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: "How can I make my Python file/package available to Matillion Python scripts? How could I handle different versions of my Python packages in the different Matillion "Versions" of my jobs?"

I think "bash" component within Matillion will be helpful for you. The only requirement here is you should be able to ssh from matillion server to any other server where your external python package exists.

Within the bash component of your Matillion job, you just need to include the ssh code to the remote server and command line to execute your python package. I believe "Here doc" or Bash Here Document is what will help you:

```
ssh -T $remote_server_ip << doc
ls -lrt
python /path/to/python_script/python_script.py

doc
```

Regarding your question about versioning I am not sure but I am also interested in knowing a solution.

Thanks